# Adding an attribute and a value to XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

My input XML is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PQ>
   <PQGetClaimAttachment>
      <USERID>XXX</USERID>
      <PASSWORD>XXX</PASSWORD>
      <hostAddress>XXX</hostAddress>
      <businessArea>CS2XAA</businessArea>
      <sourceType>2XSRCTYP</sourceType>
      <operator>GT</operator>
      <lookupDate>2015-01-01T00.00.00.000000+05:30</lookupDate>
   </PQGetClaimAttachment>
</PQ>
```

I want to convert the above xml to the below one using XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<lookupInstances xmlns="http://www.tech.com/awd/rest/v1" name="XYZ">
  <lookupParameters>
    <lookupParameter name="businessArea">CS2XAA</lookupParameter>
    <lookupParameter name="type">2XSRCTYP</lookupParameter>
    <lookupParameter name="OPER">GT</lookupParameter>
    <lookupParameter name="LDAT">2015-01-01T00.00.00.000000+05:30</lookupParameter>
  </lookupParameters>
</lookupInstances>
```

I am using the following XSLT , but it's not giving me the desired output XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <lookupInstances xmlns="http://www.tech.com/awd/rest/v1"
                name="XYZ">
                <lookupParameters>
                    <lookupParameter businessArea="{//businessArea}" />
                    <lookupParameter type="{//sourceType}" />
                    <lookupParameter OPER="{//operator}" />
                    <lookupParameter LDAT="{//lookupDate}" />
                </lookupParameters>
            </lookupInstances>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could any one please let me know where I am doing the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the output to have `name="businessArea"` attributes, it makes no sense to give them `businessArea=""` attributes.

This should do what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <lookupInstances xmlns="http://www.tech.com/awd/rest/v1"
                name="XYZ">
                <lookupParameters>
                    <lookupParameter name="businessArea">
                         <xsl:value-of select="PQ/PQGetClaimAttachment/businessArea" />
                    </lookupParameter>
                    <lookupParameter name="type">
                         <xsl:value-of select="PQ/PQGetClaimAttachment/sourceType" />
                    </lookupParameter>
                    <lookupParameter name="OPER">
                         <xsl:value-of select="PQ/PQGetClaimAttachment/operator" />
                    </lookupParameter>
                    <lookupParameter name="LDAT">
                         <xsl:value-of select="PQ/PQGetClaimAttachment/lookupDate" />
                    </lookupParameter>
                </lookupParameters>
            </lookupInstances>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's perfect..!! +1 for quick response.